# Why was the Boeing SST numbered "2707"?

Tags: aircraft-naming, boeing-sst

Boeing worked its Supersonic Transport ([Boeing SST 2707](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_2707)) design in the 1960s. They gave it the number "2707". Why was this aircraft given that number? Did it have some significant inside-Boeing relation to the B707 or was it just some number that followed another Boeing numbering scheme?

Comment: Its internal model number 733 but not 2707. The name may be a mixture of [Lockhead L-2000](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lockheed_L-2000) and B707

Comment: For those voting to close, I don't see how this could be primarily opinion based. There should be a concrete reason, however hard to discover. The only opinion based answers will be those choosing to speculate.

Answer (score 1):

The planned cruise speed was Mach 2.7 so I always assumed 2707 was a combination of Mach 2.7 and the then current Boeing 707.

Comment: But the SST had nothing at all to do with the 707, and the 707 had been in production for eight or nine years by 1966, when the "2707" designation was first used to refer to the SST. By that time, the 727 was in service, the 737 was in production and the 747 project had begun.